# Facing issue in Impress.js carousel

Tags: javascript, css, impress.js

I am trying to implement a carousel using impress.js similar to http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/02/css3-product-showcase/#/music.

I tried developing it but facing some problem like when clicked on left or right icon, the screen is moving upwards and downwards. The work that i have done is uploaded in my server. Link:
http://think360apps.co.in/evdt/issued/index.html#intro

Also the code is given below:

```
    <div class="animate-slider">
        <div id="impress" class="impress-not-supported">

        <div id="intro" class="step" data-x="0" data-y="0">
            <h2>Introducing Galaxy Nexus</h2>
            <p>Android 4.0<br /> Super Amoled 720p Screen<br /> 1.2 GHz Dual Core CPU<br /> 32 GB of storage<br /> Fast Camera</p>
            <img src="assets/img/nexus_1.jpg" width="232" height="458" alt="Galaxy Nexus" />
        </div>

        <div id="simplicity" class="step" data-x="1100" data-y="1200" data-scale="1.8" data-rotate="190">
            <h2>Simplicity in Android 4.0</h2>
            <p>Android 4.0, Ice Cream Sandwich brings an entirely new look and feel to Android. Simple layouts with subtle animations and delightful flourishes make everything feel alive. </p>
            <img src="assets/img/nexus_2.jpg" width="289" height="535" alt="Galaxy Nexus" />
        </div>

        <div id="connect" class="step" data-x="-300" data-y="600" data-scale="0.2" data-rotate="270">
            <h2>Connect &amp; Share</h2>
            <p>Real-life sharing is nuanced and rich. Galaxy Nexus makes sharing with mobile devices just as easy at it is in person. </p>
            <img src="assets/img/nexus_3.jpg" width="558" height="329" alt="Galaxy Nexus" />
        </div>

        <div id="upload" class="step" data-x="-200" data-y="1500" data-rotate="180">
            <h2>Instant Upload</h2>
            <p>Your photos upload themselves with Instant Upload, which makes it much easier to share them with family and friends.</p>
            <img src="assets/img/nexus_4.jpg" width="248" height="510" alt="Galaxy Nexus" />
        </div>

        <div id="music" class="step" data-x="-1200" data-y="1000" data-scale="0.8" data-rotate="270">
            <h2>Jam on with Google Music</h2>
            <p>Google Music makes discovery, purchase, and listening effortless and fun. Store your entire collection for free, and stream your music to your Galaxy Nexus, computer, or other Android devices.</p>
            <img src="assets/img/nexus_5.jpg" width="570" height="389" alt="Galaxy Nexus" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <a id="arrowLeft" class="arrow">&lt;</a>
    <a id="arrowRight" class="arrow">&gt;</a>
```

Please let me know where i am doing wrong.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this code to control the button:

```
<script>
$("#arrowRight").click(function () {
   impress().next();
});
$("#arrowLeft").click(function () {
   impress().prev();
});
</script>
```

By the way, the link you've given is invalid.